# Create node module "xxx is not a function"

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am creating a NW.js app.

I have created a node "sub-module" (not sure how it should be called) `update.js` :

```
function Updater() {
  if (!(this instanceof Updater)) return new Updater();
  console.log("init");
}

Updater.prototype.CheckUpdate = function() {
  console.log("Checking for update");
};

Updater.prototype.SetTimer = function() {
  console.log("set timer");
};

Updater.prototype.destroy = function destroy() {
  this.remove();
  return true;
};

module.exports = Updater;
```

I'm calling it like this in the main script, `run.js` :

```
var updater = require('./update');
updater.CheckUpdate();
updater.SetTimer();
```

But I get an error in my log file (not show above):

> "TypeError: updater.CheckUpdate is not a function"

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

Comment: right, because `Updater` doesn't have a `CheckUpdate` method. Instances of `Updater` however do.

Comment: This is right. However I don't understand neither the downvote nor the close vote (if you did them)...

Comment: not a useful question, and not solved in a way that will help future visitors. Nothing against you personally.

Comment: It just shows a misunderstanding of how prototypes work and what `require()` does, but your close vote reason is "typo"... well, nevermind, not a big deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CheckUpdate and SetTimer are properties of Updater.prototype , not Updater.
So try this:

```
var Updater = require('./update');
var updater = new Updater();
updater.CheckUpdate();
updater.SetTimer();
```